# Como utilizar template Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3, bootstrap, template

Queria utilizar o template Gentelella. Até procurei explicações mais não encontrei.

Preciso trocar um painel admin que criei alguns anos atrás por um mais novo. E vi está alternativa que não consegui implementar.

Alguém pode me ajudar como começar? Só preciso de um rumo de como começar.

Comment: Pergunta interessante, eu já tentei utilizar este tema e também não consegui, fiz tudo como manda no `github`, instalei todas as dependências e não funfo, seria interessante se alguém fizesse um tutorial dela usando `gulp` e `bower`

Answer (score -1):

Para isso você coloca dentro do head uma tag chamada link, fica assim:

```
<link href="Local que vc esta puxando seu bootstrap" rel="stylesheet">
```

rel esta dizendo que é uma folha de estilo

Depois é só vc colocar class nas tags html e nomea-las com os nomes que estão gravados no seu bootstrap

Comment: Não amigo. Chamar o bootstrap eu sei. Preciso do template de painel administrativo. Que seria este: https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html

Comment: @LuizOleia Legal por participar da comunidade mas a sua resposta não é uma solução para o problema